# Regex keep track of `)`

Tags: .net, regex

Lets say my input is `fn(a(b,c),d) fn(a,d) fn(a(b),d)` and I want `a(b,c),d` how would I write a pattern to get everything inside of the ()? The 2nd fn() is easy the first and third I don't know how to match

Comment: Are you given a whitespace character as a separator?  You could try `fn[(](\S*)[)]`.

Comment: Can `fn` contain more `fn`s, or just `a`/`b`/`c`'s? Does the input contain many `fn`s, or just one? If there are many, are they just `fn`s in a row, or can other thing be between them? How deep is the nesting - is `fn(a(b(c)))` valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [balancing group definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) for this:

```
result = Regex.Match(subject,
    @"(?<=\()              # Make sure there's a ( before the start of the match
        (?>                # now match...
           [^()]+          # any characters except parens
        |                  # or
           \(  (?<DEPTH>)  # a (, increasing the depth counter
        |                  # or
           \)  (?<-DEPTH>) # a ), decreasing the depth counter
        )*                 # any number of times
        (?(DEPTH)(?!))     # until the depth counter is zero again
      (?=\))               # Make sure there's a ) after the end of the match",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split it

```
var output=Regex.Split(input,@"(?:\)|^)[^()]*(?:\(|$)");
```

---

You would get output as

```
a(b,()c),d
a,d
a(b),d
```

Comment: Your pattern splits anything between `)` and `(`. It will icorrectly split `fn(a(),b())`, and many other variations. (Of course, we don't *know* if these are possible)

Comment: @Kobi yes..indeed..u r right..op should confirm this possibility..